# Laravel Dynamic Order By in Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table with 10 different fields. I want to be able to click the column of the table then the page will reload with the order by in the column that was selected.

I've added this to my routes:

```
Route::get('/inventory/sort/{sortby}', ['uses' => 'ItemController@index']);
```

My Controller:

```
 public function index($sortby = null) {
    $Inventory_Items = ItemDynamic::with(['Item'])
                     ->orderBy(function ($query) use($sortby) {
                         if ($sortby == "quantity") {
                           $query->orderBy('Quantity','asc');
                         } else if ($sortby == 'name') {
                           $query->orderBy('name','asc');
                         } else {
                           $query->orderBy('id','asc');
                         }
                       })
                     ->paginate(20);
        return view('adminlte::Item.index', ['Inventory_Items' => $Inventory_Items]);
    }
```

So, when I access `/inventory/sort/quantity` it should result in a order by quantity.

Instead, I get a strtolower() error.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is a bit of recursion here.  Running a query inside of a orderBy.

I would return the conditioning into the orderBy method.

```
 if($sortBy == 'desired condition') 
    { $sortBy = 'desired condition'; $dir == "asc/..."; } 
 ...orderBy($sortBy, $dir)...
```